# build a list of linked objects recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a `Foo` object that has a field referencing a list of `Bar` objects. Each `Bar` object in a list of `Bar` references a next `Foo` object. The idea is to have a list of `Foo` objects, each one with a list of `Bar` pointing to different `Foo` objects in the list (i.e., `foo1` has pointers to `foo2` and `foo5`). The last `Foo` object points to `null`. In the example below there are two `Foo` instances: `foo1` points to `foo2`, and `foo2` points to `null`.

If I want to construct a list of linked `Foo` objects, I have to start from the last object and build it in reverse. Can I do this recursively?

```
public class Foo {

    private final String id;
    private final List<Bar> barList;

    public Foo(String id, List<Bar> barList) {
        this.id = id;
        this.barList = barList;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Bar> getBarList() {
        return barList;
    }
}

public class Bar {

    private final Foo nextFoo;

    public Bar(Foo nextFoo) {
        this.nextFoo = nextFoo;
    }

    public Foo getNextFoo() {
        return nextFoo;
    }
}

public class FooListBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        buildFoosInReverse();
        // buildFoosRecursively();
    }

    public static void buildFoosInReverse() {
        List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();

        Bar bar2 = new Bar(null);
        List<Bar> bar2List = new ArrayList<Bar>();
        bar2List.add(bar2);     
        Foo foo2 = new Foo("2", bar2List);

        Bar bar1 = new Bar(foo2);
        List<Bar> bar1List = new ArrayList<Bar>();
        bar1List.add(bar1);         
        Foo foo1 = new Foo("1", bar1List);

        fooList.add(foo1);
        fooList.add(foo2);      

        System.out.println(fooList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the bar list the Foo list in reverse?

Comment: @Tezra No, each foo has a list of bars and each bar has a foo, so Foo nextFoo = thisFoo.getBarList().get(0).getNextFoo();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a little tricky because you need to sort out what needs to be instantiated when, and keep track of what references what. The trick is you need to build your Foos going down the rabbit hole, and then add the Bar on your way back out.

Here is the recursive code to do this.

```
public static List<Foo> buildFoosRecursive(String[] values) {
    ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>(values.length);
    buildFoosRecursive(values, 0, list);
    return list;
}

private static void buildFoosRecursive(String[] values, int index, List<Foo> fooList) {
    if (index >= values.length)
        return;

    List<Bar> bar1List = new ArrayList<Bar>(1);
    Foo newFoo = new Foo(values[index], bar1List);
    fooList.add(newFoo);

    buildFoosRecursive(values, index + 1, fooList);

    Bar bar1;
    if (fooList.size() > index + 1)
        bar1 = new Bar(fooList.get(index + 1));
    else
        bar1 = new Bar(null);

    bar1List.add(bar1);

    return;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. The only thing is this will build a list of Foos with each Foo pointing to the Foo at index + 1 in the list. I want the bar list to contain multiple Foo objects so that Foo1 can have links to Foo2, Foo5, Foo10 depending on what's in the Bar list. But I guess that shouldn't be too hard to work out.

Comment: @bez I can't improve it without understanding the linking logic better, but by the time anything reaches `bar1List.add(...)`, all the Foos are already in fooList, so you just need to add the bars you want. It should be simple to adjust this as you need. If there is any part of the function I can comment on to make it clearer, just let me know. (and what about it you would like explained)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `fooList` in your code is using `ArrayList` it is not `LinkedList`, if you want `LinkedList` you could use already existing implementation : [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

You can create a `LinkedList` from `ArrayList` using:

`List<Foo> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<Foo>( fooList );`

Now coming back to your question, I don't see how you can "construct" Linked List using recursion.

Recursion lends itself to solving problems like print linked list - i.e. when a linked list already exists.

When you want to construct a linked list, you need to make calls to [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)) in sequence.

Comment: I wasn't using the term linked list correctly. It's an ArrayList of linked objects such that each object holds a reference to an object of the same type.